# 502 Bad gateway error when bot deployed as service fabric stateless web api

Tags: bots, azure-service-fabric

I am getting 502 bad gateway error for bot webchat. Bot API deployed as service fabric stateless Web API. As per bot builder, they told that issue with our bot but I have deployed default template provided by bot framework. Still getting the same error. I thought the problem with Bot Authentication because It will require Microsoft AppId and AppPassword as config settings. So I have to override bot authentication filter and pass the values for AppId and AppPassword. Still getting the same error. So I have implemented logging in the Azure table in both classes BothAuthentication filter and MessagesController. Nothing log to the Azure table. So Directline API not calling my register bot. The code works fine in the emulator as emulator bypass bot authentication. Can someone tell how to resolve this issue? I have implemented basic echo bot template with stateless web API

Comment: can you try hosting a simple web api first, and see if that works? It could be a matter of adding rules to the load balancer.

Comment: Simple web api is working fine. No problem with Load Balancer. Other normal controller within same application working fine. Just problem with bot. Direct line api of bot not able to call the endpoint. I have hosted stateless web API in service fabric and enable on ports 80 for HTTP and 443 for https. Both are working fine for normal controller. Just only problem with Direct line API couldn't call bot controller.

Comment: Any luck with this? On my development machine I can call my endpoint via http://localhost:port/....  But when I use ngrok, with a named url like http://myname.ngrok.io/... the caller receives a  bad gateway 502. However, in ngrok inspector, shows all is good with the expected response.